# Delete specific index using pop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to delete `index 1 and index 16` by using `pop method` but they will not delete it from index kindly suggest if any solution for it these is page link https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire/

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
webdriver_service = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service,options=options)
url = 'https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire/'
driver.get(url)
data=[]
def main():
    for x in range(28):
        try:
            select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ville-select'))))
            select.pop(16)
            select.select_by_index(x)
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            pass
        
        try:
            click_on_search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[@value="Rechercher"])[1]')))
        except:
            pass

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click_on_search_button)
```

Comment: why do you know it didn't remove it? After removing item other items are moves and now item 17 is in place of 16, etc.

Comment: you can always add `if x >= 16: x += 1` to skip element